# Select from two tables where first table column holds the name of the column to get from second table

Tags: sql-server

This is for SQL Server.

I have table1 with a number of columns. One of  those columns is the name of a column in table2. table2 (a temp table actually) has only one row but many columns holding floats.

I want to select rows from table1 and for each row also get the value from the column in table2 that was specified in one of the columns in table1. This is not the same column name for every row.

I tried with a subquery from table2, but as that subquery is executed before the main query is the column name unknown at that time and it  just returns the name, not the value. It is also only evaluated once and not for every row

#result has one row with many float columns TT_SECC_IN | TT_SECC_OUT | TT_SECW_IN | TT_SECW_OUT.....

SELECT REGISTER,BIT32,ENDIAN,VARIABLE,SCALEFACTOR, (SELECT VARIABLE FROM #result) AS VValue 
FROM DATACONFIG 
WHERE PAID='AXBA01'

Result of query:

REGISTER | BIT32 | ENDIAN | VARIABLE    | SCALEFACTOR | VValue

1        |   0   |    0   | TT_SECC_IN  | 1.0         | TT_SECC_IN

2        |   0   |    0   | TT_SECC_OUT | 1.0         | TT_SECC_IN

3        |   0   |    0   | TT_SECW_IN  | 1.0         | TT_SECC_IN

4        |   0   |    0   | TT_SECW_OUT | 1.0         | TT_SECC_IN

In column VValue of the result I want the value for the VARIABLE column in #result

Comment: show us your sample data and your query and desired output please

Comment: `case` expression

Comment: Just do a cross join with the variables tables and then a `case` expression to pick out the right column.

Comment: Cross Join was nice, was not aware of that type of  join. Have to be careful here not to cause large result sets. However, case does not seems to be realistic, as #result can have up to about 150 columns and the number is also dynamic. (When the column is not found the resulting value should be zero)